# EF code first with existing database causing error known to many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have existing database. Then new requirement came for more tables so I created model and used code first approach to generate tables to existing db.

But when I run command

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName ListHell.CODE.flagen -force
```

I get error

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext
>   created using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can
>   only be obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an
>   existing DbCompiledModel.

I have checked all the answer related to it on SO but all are useless to my case

my dbcontext class

```
  public partial class flagen:DbContext
{
    public flagen() : base("name=LH_newEntities")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<flag> flags { get; set; }
}
```

thanksfor help

Comment: What answers? Why are they useless? If the error message is accurate there is no other answer to give. Have you mixed Db-First and Code-First contexts in the same project perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos one answer says delete the _migrationhistory and delete the migraition folder then try again I did that no result. other is exactly the same.

Comment: The error is about model-first contexts. Not migrationhistory. *Do* you have model-first or db-first contexts? Is the error accurate? Why is your class *partial*?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have existing database and doin code first its in the question

Comment: I'll bet that `flagen` is also a db-first context because it has the `partial` keyword

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos still giving the error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have removed the partial but error still there.

Comment: It's not about `partial`, it's about model- or db-first contexts. The `partial` is just an indication that you *generated* the context, instead of writing a code-first context class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and how can I write code-first context class?

Comment: That and the explicit `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`

Comment: [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no its still giving error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos note that I have another context class in the project and that is dbfirst. and pointing to same db w/ same connectstr

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the thing you sent is not helpful I have checked it out

Comment: you CANNOT mix code first with db first approaches. first it's completely pointless, secondly db first contexts can't handle modelbuilder overrides and code first contexts can't handle edmx files, so it's impossible anyways. you should clean up your codebase and decide on one strategy.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I have done this before. With identity tables. Its possible. just cant remember how

Answer (score 0):

I was sharing the connection string of codefirst and dbfirst. it turned out this will not work. I created new connection string and its works smoothly. Solved